# Getting multiple cell values that changes position monthly

Tags: excel, vba

I have this worksheet:
[image]

The data before and after that view varies monthly. The distance between the cells in that view is static. I also just want to get the data for drives C and D. There are other drives in this report that is not needed. All the drives in this worksheet belongs to one machine.

I am making a tool that can copy the

1. Drive letter
2. Machine name (Machine1.contoso.com)
3. image
4. Max value

I'm sure there needs to be some kind of a loop that needs to be done but I don't know how to find the values/cells that changes position.

Comment: So you want to search for the c or d drive and pull information relative to that cell? Just use macro recorder and record yourself searching for the cell. Then to get a fixed number of cells away, just use the offset function.

Comment: The location of C and D drives varies monthly. Will the recorder also capture that?

Comment: you can record a macro of you searching for them. Then the macro would find it just as if you were doing control+f